# Ajax achor changes into a normal anchor upon completion of an ajax request!

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following Ajax function to send a request. Something weird happens though. When the request is finished, the new button that comes back is not ajax enabled. It acts as a normal anchor would.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".UIButton a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (! $(this).data("isClicked"))
        {
            var requestData = $(this).attr("href");
            var link = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                dataType: 'js',
                url: requestData,

                beforeSend: function() {
                    $(link).fadeOut("slow");
                },

                error: function() {
                },

                success: function(response) {
                    $(link).parent().html(response);
                       $(link).stop().fadeIn("slow");
                }
            });

            // Toggle isClicked to prevent button mashing
            link.data("isClicked", true);

            // Create timeout to restore button
            setTimeout(function() { link.removeData("isClicked") }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's what comes back from the server, which is correct:
`<a class="delete" href="/users/delete/3333">Delete</a>`

Here is the original button:

```
<div class="UIButton">
   <a class="Add" href="/users/add/3333">Add</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the link did not exist when you originally bound an event listener to the `click` event, you need to re-bind the event (using `bind` in your success function),  or use `delegate` or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) to bind event handlers to events (recommended).

Using `delegate` or `live` ensures that the event is handled on matched elements now and in the future.

Here's how you would accomplish this with [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$("containing-element-selector").delegate(".UIButton a", "click", function() { 
    ... 
});
```

(this is the recommended method)

Or with `live`:

```
$(".UIButton a").live("click", function() {
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `.click()` function only affects the currently existing DOM elements. Try using `.live("click", function() {your_function_here})` instead.

See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for further information